# switching bool values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a weird issue: I have a HTML attribute that will only be true or false, i fetch it with Jquery and turn it into a boolean, then i switch it for the opposite (true to false, false to true), then i change the same HTML attribute with the new boolean value.

It works at first, when the original attr value is false and it get set to true, but not the other way around:

```
<button aria-checked="false" class="toggle-search" type="button">
    Toggle button is <span>false</span>
</button>
```

And now the Js/Jquery

```
$(".toggle-search").click(function(){      

    var status = !$(this).attr("aria-checked"); 
    // returns string, turn to bool

    $(this).attr("aria-checked",!status);
    $(this).children("span").html(!status);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kaqyhc48/4/

I dont understand what's going on with the logic, is the new value not being parsed to false or maybe being parsed to false first and then to true?

Thanks for the help

Comment: `!"false" === false`

Comment: If you know the values will only ever be `"true"` and `"false"` you can read them into `true` and `false` with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: `aria-checked="false"` will be evaluated as _true_ since it is retrieved as a string. You could use the strict equality `if ($(this).attr('aria-checked') === 'false')`

Comment: Or you could use a checkbox ;)

Comment: javascript allows for mixing types, but that does not mean you can just expect it to work out every conversion for you :) Be explicit - `!($(this).attr("aria-checked") === 'true')` etc.

Comment: as a side note, you should not use any standard Attribute that's the point in HTML5 having the `data-*` allowance on all HTML elements as your using Jquery you can then use the `$().data()` system as that does support boolean values as there not actually saved on the element only loaded form the initial HTML element

Comment: @MartinBarker aria attributes are a real thing.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

Comment: @epascarello I'm sure that was his point - use `data-` attributes instead since that's what they are for. `aria-` has another purpose :)

Comment: @Mackan `aria-checked` *is a real thing*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_checkbox_role

Comment: @JaredSmith Ah, I see. That was a more precise link :) Interesting.

Comment: @epascarello sorry I did not know about that one, I must say though please don't point to Mozilla for standards point to the standards document https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#wai-aria however my main point was as Mackan said and use the data as it's purely for javascript to keep track of things that's the purpose of `data-*` and when using jQuery you should really use `$().data()` as it uses memory and does not update or read the `DOM` unless it has to and supports Javascript values not just `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the string to a boolean value. The simplest way to do it is `value == "true"`, which returns `true`, when the string is `"true"` and `false` otherwise.

To parse it back to a string you can use `value ? "true" : "false"`.

```js
$(".toggle-search").click(function() {

  var status = $(this).attr("aria-checked") == "true";
  status = !status;
  // returns string, turn to bool

  $(this).attr("aria-checked", status);
  $(this).children("span").html(status ? "true" : "false");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button aria-checked="false" class="toggle-search" type="button">
    Toggle button is <span>false</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var status = !$(this).attr("aria-checked");` this will not convert string to bool. So replace it with `var status = 'true'== $(this).attr("aria-checked");` which will convert string to bool.

And in `.html(false)` will not be printed so use `.html((false).toString())`

```js
$(".toggle-search").click(function(){      

        var status = 'true'== $(this).attr("aria-checked");
        $(this).attr("aria-checked",!status);
        $(this).children("span").html((!status).toString());
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button aria-checked="false" class="toggle-search" type="button">
  Toggle button is <span>false</span>
</button>
```