# html method does not output "false" when passing false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a simple extension to validate an email address, but am running into some strange behavior when processing the bool value from the extension.

From the snippet you can see that boolOne and boolThree, that should read false but is empty. Is there a reason for not appending "false" when false, like it does with "true"?

If I use `String()` it works, so that's a solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#buttonValidate").click(function () {
        $("#boolOne").html($("#emailOne").IsEmail());
        $("#intOne").html(ToInt($("#emailOne").IsEmail()));
        $("#boolTwo").html($("#emailTwo").IsEmail());
        $("#intTwo").html(ToInt($("#emailTwo").IsEmail()));
        $("#boolThree").html($("#emailThree").IsEmail());
        $("#intThree").html(ToInt($("#emailFive").IsEmail()));

        console.log({ One: $("#emailOne").IsEmail() });
        console.log({ Two: $("#emailTwo").IsEmail() });
        console.log({ Three: $("#emailThree").IsEmail() });

        function ToInt(val) {
            let result = 0;

            if (val) {
                result = 1;
            }

            return result;
        }
    });
});

$.fn.IsEmail = function () {
    var result = false;
    var val = this.val();
    var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (reg.test(val)) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

```css
p.button-wrap {
  padding: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <h1>IsEmail</h1>

        <input type="text" id="emailOne" value="error" /> - bool: <span id="boolOne"></span>, int: <span id="intOne"></span>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="emailTwo" value="valid@valid.no" /> - bool: <span id="boolTwo"></span>, int: <span id="intTwo"></span>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="emailThree" value="error@error" /> - bool: <span id="boolThree"></span>, int: <span id="intThree"></span>
        <p class="button-wrap">
            <input type="button" id="buttonValidate" value="Validate" />
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Apparently `.html(false)` just removes all content of the element. I’m trying to find some documentation on that.

Comment: BTW: you should limit the code to the essential. There is only need of one DOM element to demonstrate your issue, and the function `IsMail` and `ToInt` really are not needed for it either.

Comment: I could only find it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438680/4642212).

Comment: Docs for html() stipulate argument must be string or function. Shouldn't really expect an answer to why passing `false` fails to insert anything when it is neither string or function as documented

Comment: trincot I included the code to display multiple examples to easier show the behavior. The ToInt is there to demonstrate that the value processed actually is equal to boolean true or false.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, you can force cast it to string by using `"" + boolean` which will return `"false"` instead of `false`.

Also, I took the liberty to rewrite your code a bit ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttonValidate").click(() => {
    ["One","Two","Three"].forEach( num => {
       let isEmail = $(`#email${num}`).IsEmail()
       $(`#bool${num}`).html("" + isEmail);
       $(`#int${num}`).html(isEmail ? 1 : 0);
    })
  });
});

const reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

$.fn.IsEmail = function() { return reg.test(this.val()) }
```

```css
p.button-wrap {
  padding: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>IsEmail</h1>

  <input type="text" id="emailOne" value="error" /> - bool: <span id="boolOne"></span>, int: <span id="intOne"></span>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="emailTwo" value="valid@valid.no" /> - bool: <span id="boolTwo"></span>, int: <span id="intTwo"></span>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="emailThree" value="error@error" /> - bool: <span id="boolThree"></span>, int: <span id="intThree"></span>
  <p class="button-wrap">
    <input type="button" id="buttonValidate" value="Validate" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP already knows about the solution. What they need is an _explanation_.

Comment: Exactly. And it's probably not likely I've ever need the boolean value as a string. I just got curious about this behavior and it would be great with an explanation